# contour coordinates of Voronoi diagram

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am currently working a project. For a given set of point coordinates within an image with shape of 1000*1000, I want to compute the pixels coordinates on the boundaries of the Voronoi domains associated to the points.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html

[image]
Like the example given in scipy.

How can I get a list of coordinates of those black line and dash line(within an area of (0,0) to (2, 2)).

Like(0, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5), (1.0, 0.5), (1.5, 0.5), (2.0, 0.5).
Maybe it also needs some post-process since these coordinates represent the pixel location in an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get out of an implementation in pure OpenCV, a fast solution can be computed on the GPU by rendering (say, in OpenGL or DirectX) the paraboloid `z = (x - px)^2 + (y - py)^2` at every point `(px, py)` of your point cloud, with z-buffering on, and using a different color for every paraboloid. This works because, by definition, the points of each Voronoi domain are colored with the color of the vertex they are closest to, and `z = (x - px)^2 + (y - py)^2` represents exactly that distance (squared). So you render all the paraboloids over the entire image, and let the z-buffer tell you which one is in front of which, hence closest to each vertex.

Once you have the image rendered, one pass over it to find which pixels are on the border of differently colored regions produces your answer.

Comment: Did you mean for each pixel in the whole image(if the size of the image is 1000*1000, then I have 1e+6 pixels), I compute the squared distance of each pixel at every point(the blue dots showing in the figure in my question), and store the closest(nearest) distance in a 2D array. So this array will look like some mountains, the hight is represented by the z value. 

if some pixel get two same and smallest distance in computing, which means it is the border?

Comment: Conceptually yes. In practice, you don't write code to compute all that yourself, you just define one 3D paraboloid shape (a mesh) with the appropriate tassellation in OpenGL or DirectX, instantiate one at each of the points of your set, and then let the GPU do the calculations for you in the process of rendering the "scene" of paraboloids into the image.

Answer (score 0):

The vertices attribute of the voronoi diagram contains the coordinates of each for the Voronoi vertices and the regions attribute contains the ids of the relevant vertices for each Voronoi cell. So you need to mix these data structures to get the coordinates for a given cell (and then process it again to get the pixel locations).

Here is example code with a few more points in as input to the Voronoi diagram so that it is a little clearer what is going on when looking up Voronoi vertices in the vertices attribute.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> points = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2],[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [0, 3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 3], [3, 2], [3,1], [3,0]])
>>> from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d
>>> vor = Voronoi(points)
>>> vor.vertices
array([[0.5, 2.5],
       [1.5, 2.5],
       [2.5, 2.5],
       [2.5, 0.5],
       [2.5, 1.5],
       [0.5, 0.5],
       [0.5, 1.5],
       [1.5, 0.5],
       [1.5, 1.5]])
>>> vor.regions
[[], [-1, 0], [2, -1, 1], [-1, 1, 0], [4, -1, 3], [4, 2, -1], [3, -1], [2, -1], [8, 6, 5, 7], [7, 5, -1], [5, -1, 6], [1, 8, 6, 0], [8, 7, 3, 4], [5, -1], [-1, 6, 0], [3, 7, -1], [8, 1, 2, 4]]
>>> vor.regions[8]
[8, 6, 5, 7]
>>> vor.regions[11]
[1, 8, 6, 0]
>>> vor.vertices[vor.regions[8]]
array([[1.5, 1.5],
       [0.5, 1.5],
       [0.5, 0.5],
       [1.5, 0.5]])
>>> vor.vertices[vor.regions[11]]
array([[1.5, 2.5],
       [1.5, 1.5],
       [0.5, 1.5],
       [0.5, 2.5]])
```

Then you can convert to pixel coordinates depending on the size of your Voronoi diagram relative to the image:

```
vor.vertices[vor.regions[11]]*1000/3
array([[500.        , 833.33333333],
       [500.        , 500.        ],
       [166.66666667, 500.        ],
       [166.66666667, 833.33333333]])
```